# How do I insert value after match within a loop

Tags: sed

At first, I am pretty new into bash scripting.

So I have 2 files, lets call them A and B.

In A are URLs and in B are several logs.
What I want is, insert a $actual_count after every occurrence of $element

There is only 1 $actual_count for 1 $element

```
IFS=',' read -r -a array < $1
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
        actual_count=`cat $2 | grep $element |grep css | wc -l`
        sed -i ':'"$element"': a '"$actual_count"'' daily_output
done
```

this code returns me after a found $element

all $actual_count of this loop squared and multiplied with all elements of the array.

Like (all $actual_count generated in this loop)²*sizeof array. (Thats a lot).

I don't know where I messed up that bad.

I hope you can help me.

Sorry for my bad english xD

Kind regards fune

Edit: if I use a fixed search pattern, then it works fine.

Edit 2:
thx for your answer!

Soo this the file for the array:

```
this/is/the/first.html,this/is/the/sec.html,this/is/the/third.html,this/is/the/forth.html,this/is/the/fifth.html,an/so/on.html
```

the file for actual_count is a apache-access logfile.

I want my result like this:

```
this/is/the/first.html
2
this/is/the/sec.html
3
this/is/the/third.html
0
this/is/the/forth.html
1
...
```

Comment: The `$1` file, it has exactly 1 line with comma-separated elements? You'll want to show us what's in A and B, and show us what the desired output should look like.

Comment: Thx for your answer glenn! I posted it on as answer to my question, due the format

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks, not only concerning your original question, but hopefully helpful:

1. `cat $2 | grep $element` is a useless pipe. You can directy do `grep $element $2`
2. whether `grep $element |grep css` makes sense is up to whether `$element` and `css` appear in a fixed order in the line. In this case it would be better to combine them to something like `"$element.*css"` or the other way round
3. `grep css | wc -l` can be replaced by `grep -c css` (`grep -c` returns the number of matching lines)
4. Look at your quoting: `':'"$element"': a '"$actual_count"''` consists of five elements with altering quoting (with the last one empty!). You could put everything together in double quotes to achieve the same: `":$element: a $actual_count"`
5. What do you expect the `sed` script to do? Let's look at the script after expansion: `:this/is/the/first.html: a 2` is supposed to do what? It's just a label (jump mark) and does nothing. But actually I see no need for `sed` here.

To get your given output the inner part of the loop just need to output the `$element` and in the following line the number of matching lines:

```
    echo $element
    echo $(grep -c "$element.*css" $2)
```